# Seaborn Catplot not showing text labels in x axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-science

i am trying to make a bar catplot with a `long dataframe` that has three columns: property, value and playlist. Basically it was a wide dataframe that i converted to long format using `pd.melt()`. the problem is that whenever i try to plot it with a bar catplot the categorical data that should be on the `x axis` that corresponds to the property column, is just showing up as numbers.
Here is an image of how my dataframe looks:
([image: dataframe])

and here are my code and how the plot currently looks:

- code:

```py
        #bar catplot
        bar_catplot = sns.catplot(
            kind="bar", x="property", y="value", hue="playlist", legend=True, data=long_frame2
        )
        bar_catplot_figure = bar_catplot.fig
        catplot_render = mpld3.fig_to_html(bar_catplot_figure)
```

- and how the plot currently looks:
  [image: bar catplot].
  Thank you in advance!

---

Comment: What is the output of `long_frame2.head()` in python directly (not excel)? You can edit the post and copy-paste there.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your plot, I am seeing what you say you expect to see with `g = sns.catplot(data=df, x='property', y='value', kind='bar', hue='playlist', ci=None)`

Comment: It turned out to be not a problem of the plot itself, but because mpld3 (the library that i am using for rendering plots in html) don't support categorical data in `x-axis` labels. I solved it by encoding the plot to base64 and then passing that to html. Thanks for your help!